# Custom font issue in Xcode 6 storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, custom-font

I am using a custom font in my iOS App and using the new Xcode 6. As you know, in Xcode 6 you can use custom fonts in the storyboard. I want to use such functionally, and so I've added a new custom font to my project and added the file name to the Info.plist. From that moment on it was available in the storyboard for any label, so I used it for one of my label, but when I run the App, the font is presented is Helvetica and not in the custom font I chose. Has anyone encountered such issue?

The screenshot from the storyboard of a label that used the font
[image: The screen shot from the storyboard]

The screenshot from the info.plist
[image: The screen shot from the info.plist]

The screenshot of the filename from the project
[image: The screenshot of the filename from the project]

The screenshot from the runtime inspector of the same label
[image: The screenshot from the runtime inspector of the same label]

Comment: What program is that last screenshot from?

Comment: Also, why are the plist names of the fonts not the same as the file names? That could be the problem.

Comment: The program is called Reveal.

Comment: Thought so, was asking because I wasn't sure if it might be an issue with Reveal getting the custom font names. Maybe. Also, my second question still stands about the plist and file names.

Comment: In the App, the label is presented with Helvetica as well. So in this case, it seems to be consistent with the what Reveal is presenting. As for the Second comment, you are right, my bad, I've made a screenshot of only two out of the four fonts I've added to the project. I'll update the screenshot.

Comment: Hmm... what happens if you test it by setting the font in code? `[UIFont fontWithName:@"LobsterTwo-Regular" size:25];`

Comment: Also, check the actual full name of the font. Open the inspector CMD-I on the rtf files and check the full name is correct.

Comment: I got the same error here, any news on that?